# "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source" with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=id,mySite

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried MS Graph API with following GET request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=id,mySite`

However, it reports error `Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source`.

It works if I remove `mySite` or change it with another user property such as `userPrincipalName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the `users` endpoint (i.e. the collection of users). From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list):

> Note: Listing users returns a default set of properties only
>   (businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail,
>   mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname,
>   userPrincipalName). Use $select to get the other properties and
>   relationships for the user object. However, only the following
>   properties can be selected for individual users, and not for collections of users: aboutMe, birthday, hireDate, interests, mySite, pastProjects, preferredName, responsibilities, schools, skills, mailboxSettings

For easier reading, the list of unsupported properties are:

- aboutMe
- birthday
- hireDate
- interests
- **mySite**
- pastProjects
- preferredName
- responsibilities
- schools
- skills
- mailboxSettings